# Не получается получить сумму из хеш таблицы, через упрощённый цикл и присвоить сумму в переменную

Tags: java, for, хеширование, java-hashmap

Начинаю изучать java через ЯП, столкнулся с такой задачей, не могу решить:

> В таблице собраны имена клиентов зоомагазина и сумма, на которую они делали заказы. Посчитайте, сколько всего денег было потрачено на питомцев.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Double> orders = new HashMap<>();
    orders.put("Иван И.", 4345.5);
    orders.put("Ольга С.", 76564.43);
    orders.put("Александр Т.", 1234.86);
    orders.put("Александр Р.", 23432.87);
    orders.put("Екатерина О.", 1034753.6);
    orders.put("Ярослав В.", 450.0);

    Double sum = 0; // Объявите переменную, где будет сохранена общая сумма
    for (String sum : orders.values()) { // Пройдитесь в цикле по значениям
          sum = sum + 1;
    }

    System.out.println("Всего было совершено заказов на сумму: " + sum);
}
```

Решил объявить переменную sum (обёртка Double), присвоить ей значение 0, выполнить упрощённый цикл и как результат присвоить значение переменной sum, пытался вернуть значение, то тоже тщетно.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как нужно сделать, и почему так, я буду невероятно благодарен!

Comment: может не делать одинаковые имена sum for (Double sum1 ...){ sum = sum + sum1; }

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Представленный код не компилируется, так как кроме того, что `sum` используется дважды, так ещё и во втором случае указан неверный тип `String` вместо `Double`.  Также следует отметить, что не стоит использовать `Double` для работы с _фиксированной_ точкой в финансовых расчётах из-за ошибок округления

Answer (score 0):

Простой цикд по `Double` значениям:

```java
Double total = 0.0;

for (Double v : orders.values()) {
    total += v;
}

System.out.println("Всего было совершено заказов на сумму: " + total);
```

---

С использованием Stream API:

```java
Double total = orders.values()
    .stream()
    .reduce(0.0, Double::sum);
// или так
double total2 = orders.values()
    .stream()
    .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
    .sum();
```

---

Также следует отметить, что для финансовых вычислений тип с плавающей точкой `Double` не подходит из-за ошибок округления при представлении дробных чисел, и гораздо лучше использовать тип `BigDecimal`.